# Access violations in the BDE when adding indexes

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, bde

I'm attempting to add an index to a fairly large (1.2 million records) DBase 7 table with memo fields.

When I add the first 2 indexes, it works with no problem. However, when I attempt to add the 3rd index, which is a one field index with no options or descfields, I get the following access violation:

```
Access violation at 0x00400007: write of address 0x00a43820
```

I've traced through DBTables and it fails on `Check(DbiAddIndex(DBHandle, Handle, nil, nil, IndexDesc, nil));` in TTable.AddIndex.

I've tried tracing into DbiAddIndex, but it's part of the BDE module, and I don't have the .pas or a .dcu with debug symbols.

Comment: The BDE has quite a few bugs, especially regarding index creation on large tables. I wish you luck to find the problem but I don't have much hope. We had index creation fail on the same table on one computer while it worked on another one and never found out what the cause was. I wish I could recommend an alternative access method for DBase tables, but tdbf does have severe shortcomings regarding indexes, and I don't know of any other that works well.

Comment: @dummzeuch Yeah, that's what I was afraid of.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set `MAXBUFSIZE` to the maximum of `65535` in the BDE Administrator under Configuration\System\INIT ?
It solved my problem when using `TTable.AddIndex`.